# Use pdfbox to get the gradient color of the word

Tags: pdfbox

Is there a way to get the gradient color attribute of the word using pdfbox?

my file:[new york.pdf](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wlrt0kM9mDI5nqulISB24Ri3xvTnPIeq/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: No, this is a shape in the form of text, and two axial shading patterns are used to fill the shape. You can look at the file with PDFDebugger to see more.

Comment: There are text drawing instructions in your PDF but they draw completely transparent text (non-stroking alpha = 0); they only are there to allow text extraction / copy&paste. What you _see_ is the result of some paths filled with some patterns as @Tilman told you.

Comment: Thanks to the above two answers.I discovered the "scn" value through PDFDebugger, scn is a command to set color in PDF, usually used to set fill or stroke color. I want to get the position and color of words in this document, is there any other way?

Comment: Is there a way to get the picture through the properties of the axial gradient? Now that I got the `PDAbstractPattern` , I don’t know how to generate a picture in the next step

Comment: The rendering is dependent of many things. That's why it's so complex.